# C++ and .Net core not building in single Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have following dockerfile. It is compiling c++ as well as .net projects.

When I add .net code C++ layers are not working. If I remove .Net Layers then C++ Layers are working.

Is this something can't be done in single file?

```
# GCC support can be specified at major, minor, or micro version
# (e.g. 8, 8.2 or 8.2.0).
# See https://hub.docker.com/r/library/gcc/ for all supported GCC
# tags from Docker Hub.
# See https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/gcc/ for more on how to use this image
FROM gcc:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libmotif-dev

# These commands copy your files into the specified directory in the image
# and set that as the working location
COPY . /usr/src/myapp

COPY ca-8-5-5-linux-x86-64/redist /usr/src/myapp/ca-8-5-5-linux-x86-64/sdk/demo

WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp/ca-8-5-5-linux-x86-64/sdk/samplecode/unix/
# This command compiles your app using GCC, adjust for your source code
RUN make

############################################################################################### 
NEED HELP HERE. ABOVE IS NOT WORKING. IF I REMOVE FOLLOWING THEN ABOVE WORKS.
###############################################################################################


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-dotnet-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

COPY . .

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["sdk/samplecode/myAppExport/myAppExport.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "myAppExport.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "sdk/samplecode/myAppExport/myAppExport.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "sdk/samplecode/myAppExport/myAppExport.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myAppExport.dll"]
```

Following is the log I am having when both "Make" and dotnet build is together.

```
[+] Building 19.4s (20/20) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.70kB                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal                                                                                                  0.5s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0-focal                                                                                              0.4s
 => [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal@sha256:213bd9012c064e2e80c9ffc17e4e4ebd97fe01a232370af2eab31ecf4c773fcb                                      0.0s
 => [base 1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0-focal@sha256:9adcd9a2eee0506f461f81226bea8d725c5111809f1afcd12534c523f6406665                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 172.90MB                                                                                                                                    3.3s
 => CACHED [base 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [base 3/4] RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/7] COPY [sdk/samplecode/myAppExport/myAppExport.csproj, ./]                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "myAppExport.csproj"                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [build 5/7] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                 5.6s
 => [base 4/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                  5.6s
 => [final 1/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                             0.1s
 => [build 6/7] WORKDIR /src/.                                                                                                                                           0.1s
 => [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "sdk/samplecode/myAppExport/myAppExport.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build                                                      5.5s
 => [publish 1/1] RUN dotnet publish "sdk/samplecode/myAppExport/myAppExport.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish                                                2.3s
 => [final 2/2] COPY --from=publish /app/publish .                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                   1.8s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                  1.8s
 => => writing image sha256:96304565f390cf4ba352b792e6fb93c96832cdb41b56cd465feacf34f3f5005c                                                                             0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/myAppextract:1                                                                                                                   0.0s
```

Following is the logs when only gcc part is in dockerfile (removed dotnet part from dockerfile).

```
[+] Building 10.8s (12/12) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.74kB                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/gcc:latest                                                                                                                                  3.5s
 => [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/gcc:latest@sha256:084eaedf8e3c51f3db939ad7ed2b1455ff9ce4705845a014fb9fe5577b35c901                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                              0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 54.94kB                                                                                                                                                           0.1s 
 => CACHED [2/7] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [3/7] RUN apt-get install -y libmotif-dev                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => [4/7] COPY . /usr/src/myapp                                                                                                                                                                2.8s 
 => [5/7] COPY ca-8-5-5-linux-x86-64/redist /usr/src/myapp/ca-8-5-5-linux-x86-64/sdk/demo                                                                                                      0.6s
 => [6/7] WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp/ca-8-5-5-linux-x86-64/sdk/samplecode/unix/                                                                                                                    0.1s
 => [7/7] RUN make                                                                                                                                                                             1.9s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                         1.7s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                        1.6s 
 => => writing image sha256:6904800ca9760db29751820b15f8952213ad084955f62c03ef98b6723b484420                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/myappextract:1
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean; do you have a specific error message?  If you're building two separate applications, does it make sense to run them in two separate containers built on two separate images?

Comment: I have updated question to differentiate what is getting generated. First log is when both gcc and dotnet are present in dockerfile. We can see that gcc logs are not present in that. Second log is when I keep only gcc part and remove dotnet part. in second part gcc build logs are visible.

Comment: And these are not 2 seperate applications. gcc only builds dependency for .net core project. In the end only .net core application will run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I changed approach to the problem.

instead of doing `FROM gcc:latest` I added `build-essential` in following.

`RUN apt-get install -y libmotif-dev build-essential`

and that installed all required `gcc` and `make` dependencies and things are working as expected now.